# Sails: Using NODE_ENV=production not working, while NODE_ENV=prod works fine

Tags: sails.js, pm2

I have config/env/production.js with production config.

When I try to start the server using PM2, it does not work. The server does not start and the process times out.

```
NODE_ENV=production pm2 start app.js
```

On renaming config/env/production.js to config/env/prod.js and using

```
NODE_ENV=prod pm2 start app.js
```

It works fine

This seems to be related to permission issues. I also tried it using 'sudo' but it did not help.

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: Try to move config/production.js to config/env/production.js, and do not forget, production environment is special.
https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/configuration#?environmentspecific-files-config-env

Comment: @andreyunugro Sorry, I meant config/env/ there.

Answer (score 1):

Try to start the server using:

```
pm2 start app.js -- --prod
```